# Cypher query return related nodes as children

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am using the Neo4j .NET Client `ExecuteGetCypherResults` to run cypher. It expects everything to come back in a single column. I have simple class `JobType` which contains a list of `JobSpecialties` on it. In the database this is modeled as the Types having a relationship to the Specialties.

[image]

I need a cypher query that returns the results as such, in a single column. The related `Specialties` should be a child property of the `Type` node I would expect the query to look like this:

```
start s=node:node_auto_index(StartType='JobTypes')
match s-[:starts]->t, t-[:SubTypes]->ts
return {Id: t.Id, Name: t.Name, JobSpecialties: ts}
```

But this doesn't work. I can't figure out from the docs if this is even possible. If there is a better way to get the result back to the .Net client, I am open to suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

```
start s=node:node_auto_index(StartType='JobTypes')
match s-[:SubTypes]->js
return s.Id, s.Name,  js;
```

Comment: He's asking for the results in a single column (as in, no commas in the return clause). Specifically he's asking for this because the [.Net Neo4jClient](http://hg.readify.net/neo4jclient/wiki/Home) throws errors when you try to return multiple columns.

Comment: should work like this: start s=node:node_auto_index(StartType='JobTypes')
match s-[:SubTypes]->js
return [s.Id, s.Name,  js];

Comment: @MichaelHunger You can't have different types in an array projection, Cypher freaks out. If you include a string and a node in an array, the node gets converted into it's longest possible form (each property pointing to a url for the node). It's unusable.

Comment: @Tyrsius You can in 1.9-SNAPSHOT now.

Comment: @WesFreeman Good to know. I'll download that on Monday, but I imagine the client will need to be updated for that as well.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the .Net client needs some updating for cypher. Cypher doesn't support building maps on the fly yet, although it is something that is in the feature request list already...

You can create an array with your results (but as of 1.9.M04, they need to be the same type to be merged into the array):
http://console.neo4j.org/r/xo7voi

I've actually submitted a pull request (through back channels, since it broke some unit tests) to fix that (so you can have multiple types in an array built on the fly), but I think there are some concerns whether merging of different types is a good idea.

https://github.com/wfreeman/neo4j/commit/ca457ace0df4732376833b8694e4affac4143244

*Update:* This will be fixed in 1.9.M05/1.9.GA. Now you can build an array with any type mixed:
http://console.neo4j.org/r/vm4f83

Answer (score 0):

`ExecuteGetCypherResults` does support multiple columns, you just need to kick our deserializer into a different mode. This is an implementation detail generally hidden behind our higher level APIs, which is why this isn't obvious.

When you call `new CypherQuery`, pass `CypherResultMode.Projection` instead of `CypherResultMode.Set`.

I actually can't remember why we have this. Sometime, I'll need to dig through the lower levels and try and kill it. Pull requests welcomed. :)

As a preference though, we always prefer people to use the higher level APIs (but we recognise there are some limitations).

Comment: Unfortunately your higher level API's don't work for a lot of things, as [you state here](http://hg.readify.net/neo4jclient/issue/45/cyper-should-allow-for-flexible-order-of). We can't start using an API that doesn't work, so we are stuck with the lower-level one. The `Projection` mode is helpful, but it looks like it doesn't do actual projection, just aggregation. To agglomerate them on the client you need a special type to hold each column, and then loop through the results to put them in the final type. Is there a better way to do this? I don't want to make a class for each projection.

Comment: Doesn't this test demonstrate using the high level APIs to query the same data?

https://bitbucket.org/Readify/neo4jclient/commits/d51442b33ab65c11aee0b56183d74ff18626f42f

Comment: As of build 1.0.0.504, we now have a *much* more flexible fluent API and issue 45 (https://bitbucket.org/Readify/neo4jclient/issue/45) is now closed.

Comment: So if I try to use an anonymous type, like in your test, I get an error about anonymous types not having publicalyl settable properties.  If I use a type, I get this error: "Somehow targetObject ended up as null. We weren't expecting this to happen". So I don't see how your test could possibly work. Also, if I take out the JobSpecialties `CollectAs`, I can see that the Types are getting duplicated for each of their specialties, so this isn't even going to solve the aggregation issue when it does work.

Comment: So looking closer at your test, all you are doing is verifying that the query you build looks the same as a manually written query. You don't try to verify that the query can *actually be executed by your client*. Which it cant.